# Android App began crashing, I can't explain it

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I was putting the finishing touches on my app today. I created a layout-large main.xml, and a drawable-hdpi for a few of my app's images. That was all working fine, on both the WVGA and HVGA emulators. Then I added a "Help" button, with no associated code, into my menu-key menu. That was also working. I can't remember changing anything else, but now when attempting to load the main activity of my app I get a force close error, and this in my logcat:

> 10-07 18:17:08.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nickavv.quickchange/com.nickavv.quickchange.QuickChange}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-07 18:17:08.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   10-07 18:17:08.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   10-07 18:17:08.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   10-07 18:17:08.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   10-07 18:17:08.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   10-07 18:17:08.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   10-07 18:17:08.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   10-07 18:17:08.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-07 18:17:08.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   10-07 18:17:08.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   10-07 18:17:08.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   10-07 18:17:08.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   10-07 18:17:08.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-07 18:17:08.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at com.nickavv.quickchange.QuickChange.onCreate(QuickChange.java:155)
>   10-07 18:17:08.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   10-07 18:17:08.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(325):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

Thanks for the help, if you need to know anything else just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a null pointer exception on line 155 of QuickChange.java. Examine the code in that area of the app.

Comment: Got it, I can't believe myself sometimes, haha. Thank you for you help.